# There has been an error processing your request in magento2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Setup version for module 'Magento_MsrpSampleData' is not specified
Error log record number: 1734385553

the above said error showing when i reload the pages after installing the theme..

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Magento installation directory and open command prompt and run the below commands.

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Magento_MsrpSampleData
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```